# Android: child fragment manager cannot find fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have problem when using the child fragment manager. In one of my fragments `onCreateView()` method i use

```
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment);
```

which works fine in the simulator, as it probably should. However when syncing to my tablet it returns `null` which breaks my apps functionality. I also tried to use in other methods such as `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onActivityCreated` and `onInflate`, the result stays the same.

Actually i don't really know what i should do or look for as the fragment should be present (it is displayed). So it's probably something about the fragment manager. But as i am relatively new to Android i don't have any ideas.

EDIT:

Okay i just found something out. On my tablet i can use `getFragmentManager()`, on the simulator i cant (so this is vice-versa).

So on Tablet (API 19):

```
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment); // = null
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment); // = Fragment
```

and on the Simulator API 23

```
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment); // = Fragment
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment); // = null
```

EDIT 2:

So my temporary solution:

```
        ProductCategoryListFragment fragment = (ProductCategoryListFragment)getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment);
        if(null == fragment) {
            fragment = (ProductCategoryListFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.productcategorylist_fragment);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you use the child fragment manager to add the fragment you are looking for to the view hierarchy?

Comment: Well first of all it works in the simulator. And as the fragment i am trying to get is nested inside the fragment, i guess child fragment manager should be correct

Comment: Uffff... thanks for your answer. Currently it behaves like this: Simulator, API 23 -> `getChildFragmentManager()`: ok, `getFragmentManager()`: null, Tablet, API 19 -> `getChildFragmentManager()`: null, `getFragmentManager()`: ok,

Comment: Do you really need to have nested fragments in this particular case? If not, maybe it would be a good idea to migrate to using the fragment manager and not the child fragment manager.

Comment: Well "really need to"... they are actually reusable components so i'd rather keep them in Fragments. However the temporary solution queries both. I could maybe check for the Android API version first as well... Thanks anyway

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion to this, or only the workaround? And did the workaround give any unintended results?
I have the exact same problem - on a tablet (A10-70) running KitKat 4.4.2 (API 19).

Comment: Actually i couldn't find more insights. I just have the workaround, which so far seems to work for all tested simulators and devices in different APIs. So it seems to be API related. My code just checks for a `null` value after using `getChildFragmentManager` and in that case uses the `getFragmentManager`

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Here is a demo: https://github.com/evgenyneu/DemoChildFragment

Comment: Reported to Google: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199128